# Issue ListVies and Swiperefresh

Tags: android, listview

I am using swipe refresh in a layout that contains a list view. Problem facing is that when I scroll down the list its OK but when scroll up the list it calls on refresh method. So can't access upper items in list view

So how do I make such that only after the list view is scrolled up completely refresh is called? I tried placing android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout at starting. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you could subcalss `SwipeRefreshLayout` and provide a suitable implementation for `canChildScrollUp` to check if your ListView reached the to (its first child is completely visible), and then use it in your Layout. E.g.

```
public class MySwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

private AbsListView mTargetView;

public MySwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if (mTargetView == null) {
        if (!(getChildAt(0) instanceof AbsListView)) {
            return true;
        }
        mTargetView = (AbsListView) getChildAt(0);
    }
    if (mTargetView.getChildCount() > 0 && mTargetView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
        return mTargetView.getChildAt(0).getTop() > 0;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

you could adapt it to your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,

Comment: I am new to android, So can you please tell where in mMain Activity do i call this class.

Comment: public class Tab3 extends Fragment {

    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
     Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, Nullable ViewGroup container, Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2,container,false);
 @Blackbelt

Comment: Continued..... final SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)v. findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
      listViewa = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);

  mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
           @Override
           public void onRefresh() {

               }
            }
        });
   return v;
    }

Comment: Check what does "subclass" in Java mean, and how to declare a custom layout in the XML. Once you understand those concepts android will take care of the rest

Comment: what will be AttributeSet when i call this method

Comment: MySwipRefreshLayout a = new MySwipeRefreshLayout ( getContext(), ??)

Comment: You have to declare the subclass in your layout instead.of the one provided by android and use findViewById to retrieve the instance

Comment: I have declared it in layout xml file and inside it i placed listview